# How can I get rid of reed?

Tags: weeds

I have a pretty large pond in my garden which is being overgrown with common reed.

Does anyone have a method to get rid of it? In an ecological way of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wade in and yank them out.  Your pond may be deeper and larger but manual removal is still very effective.  Try using a floating pool item to get out to the problem